# When to use Grid item vs when not to use Grid Item to align and justify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am curious about when I should use `Grid item` in order to take advantage of the `Grid container` props such as `justify` or `alignItems`. I was under the impression that these attributes can be only applied to the `Grid item` inside the `Grid container`. However, it does not seem so from my example (see: "option two).

For example, let's consider this simple scenario: I want a way to display three Typography text, one next the other with some space in between.

**Option one:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-tharp-0tof1

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      direction="row"
      justify="space-between"
      style={{ minHeight: "100px", backgroundColor: "yellow" }}
    >
      <Grid item>
        <Typography> First text </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Typography> Second text </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Typography> Third text </Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

**Option two:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-northcutt-kjbef

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      direction="column"
      justify="space-between"
      style={{ minHeight: "100px", backgroundColor: "yellow" }}
    >
      <Typography> First text </Typography>
      <Typography> Second text </Typography>
      <Typography> Third text </Typography>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Why does `justify` and `direction` works directly on `Typography` as in **option two**? Should not they only work on `Grid item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, the `Grid` css will be applied to all Grid's children (independently if children are `Grid item` or `Typography`).

To explain better what I'm saying lets inspect your codesandbox examples:

**Option one**:

[image]

**Option two**:

[image]

In both cases, the div father (`MuiGrid-root`) will apllies his style to children.

Comment: Thanks. Where would you use `Grid item` then?
And, in my example, would you suggest to go with option one using always `Grid item` or option two?

Comment: No problem @Magofoco, as you can see from inspector, Grid item gives you an additional div (`MuiGrid-item`) so if you have more than one component in item (for example a typography and a textfield) I suggest you to use `Grid item` (in this way you could apply the same css to all the objects inside the item). Otherwise use just typography components like option 2.